# Disabel/Enable button based on if checkbox is checked or unchecked

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a check box which if checked the button enables. If the checkbox is unchecked the button should be disabled.

Could someone help me with this? I think I'm very close just missing a way to connect these lines.

Thanks in advance!

```
<button disabled="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/xxxxxxxxxxx'});return false;">Plan</button>

<td width="10px" style="min-width: 10px"></td>
<td width="70%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="TOS" value="Accept" onClick="button enabled"> I agree to Terms of Service agreement.
</td>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript to include? Also, it's recommended to _not_ use inline event handlers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: JavaScript is possible, but I don't have the same code in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can work on something like this.

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('myCheckbox')
const planbtn = document.getElementById('planBtn')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    planbtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    planbtn.disabled = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="planBtn" disabled="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/xxxxxxxxxxx'});return false;">Plan</button>

<td width="10px" style="min-width: 10px"></td>
<td width="70%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="TOS" value="Accept" id="myCheckbox"> I agree to Terms of Service agreement.
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Bechir, but the above code doesn't seem to work with HTML in Squarespace.

Comment: The first section have to be in javascript not HTML, I'm not familiar with Squarespace but I believe you can inject javascript in it, of course if your plan support javascript

Comment: Let me checkout how this works one moment!

Comment: I have added the JS code with <script and </script> in a HTML block (that's how it supposed to work in SquareSpace), but the button doesn't seem to enable.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want to do is the following:

```js
document.getElementById('TOS').onclick = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('plan').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('plan').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<button disabled="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/xxxxxxxxxxx'});return false;" id="plan">Plan</button>
<!-- id="plan" has been added for reference in JS -->

<td width="10px" style="min-width: 10px"></td>
<td width="70%">
  <input id="TOS" type="checkbox" name="TOS" value="Accept" onClick="button enabled"> I agree to Terms of Service agreement.
  <!-- id="TOS" has been added for reference in JS -->
</td>
```

All this does, is when the `checkbox` `input` has been clicked, the code checks to see if it is `checked`. If so, it sets `disabled` to `false` for the button. Otherwise, the `disabled` property of the button is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variation that's essentially the same as the others:

```
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const chk = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");

chk.addEventListener("click", () => { handleClick(btn); });

function handleClick(btn) {
    btn.disabled = !btn.disabled;
}
```

It finds the `button` element, finds your `checkbox`, and then listens for a click.  It toggles the button's `disabled` attribute with that click.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML & CSS Solution

***Do the following:***

**HTML**

*Markup*

- Move checkbox before the button.
- Remove the `<td>` if it isn't in a `<tr>` inside a `<table>` then it's invalid HTML. If you are using a table as layout and not for data then it's not sementic.
- Add a `<label>` after the button.

*Attributes*

<sup>The values do not have to be exactly what is in the examples. They are specific to avoid any confusion and some will be reused specifically in another property.</sup>

- Add the following to checkbox:

  - `id="`*TOS*`"`
- Add the following to button:

  - `class="`*cal*`"` See CSS
  - `type="button"` Just in case the button is inside a `<form>`
- Remove the `disabled` attribute from button. Note the only value assigned to `disabled` is a Boolean: `true` or `false`.
- Remove the JavaScript from button. Keep presentation (CSS), structure (HTML), and content (JavaScript) separate from each other as much as possible. The correct way isn't `disabled="...."` it's `onclick="..."`. That `onclick="..."` is called an inline event attribute or inline event handler, ***but*** avoid using them as well because [inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). The proper way is to either write the JavaScript on a external file or in a `<script>` block, the latter is demonstrated in the example below.
- Add the following to the `<label>`:

  - `for="`*TOS*`"` This will associate `<label>` with the checkbox. Now as long as they are both on the same page (no matter how far apart they are), clicking one will also click the other.
  - `class="`*chx*`"` See CSS.

**CSS**

<sup>There is some extensive CSS in the example so only the important aspects will be discussed. What isn't mentioned is for aesthetics.</sup>

*Checkbox*

- The styles assigned to `#TOS` is just to hide it visually but not from screenreaders, if you're not concerned about sight impaired users then `display: none` is sufficient:

  ```
  #TOS {
    position: absolute; 
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0); clip-path: inset(50%);
    width: 1px; height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;
  }
  ```

  **Note:** The whole purpose of relocating and hiding the checkbox is because CSS operates in a casscading pattern, which requires that selectors that have an alternate state (ex. checked/unchecked) can dictate the styles of oyher selectors that are either within or after (under) of that that selector in the HTML layout. The next styles demonstrate this relationship between checkbox (`input#TOS`) and button (`button.cal`) and checkbox (`input#TOS`) and label (`label.chx`).

*Button*

- In default state, `.cal` is disabled (do not confuse it's state with `disabled` attribute, it will not be used because JavaScript is needed to change it.):

  ```
  .cal {
    pointer-events: none; /* Can't click on it */
    color: white; background: lightgrey;
    outline: none; /* Can't focus on it */
  }
  ```

  When the checkbox is checked, `.cal` is enabled, the `+` is an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) which specifies that whatever follows afterwards is the selector assigned the styles:

  ```
  #TOS:checked+.cal {
    pointer-events: auto; /* Can click it */
    color: black; background: white;
    outline: initial; /* Can focus on it */
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  ```

*Label*

- Also, when the checkbox is checked the label changes as well. The label is now the only way the hidden checkbox can be checked/unchecked because the label has `for="TOS"` which links them together. The label has two [pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before). `::after` has the text next to the fake checkbox. `::before` consists of two Unicode characters which serves as a substitute for the hidden checkbox. The `~` is a [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) which works like the adjacent sibling combinator but instead of stopping at the selector right afterwards, it continues to find all selectors thereafter:

  ```
  .chx::before {
    content: '\002b1b'; /* ⬛ a large black square as default */
    ...
  } 
  /* When checkbox is checked label.chx changes it's fake checkbox */ 
  #TOS:checked~.chx::before {
    content: '\002611\00fe0f'; /* ☑️ a checkbox check */
  }
  ```

### Example

```js
/* This is a proper onevent property - 
if button.cal is clicked the anonymous function will be invoked.
*/
document.querySelector('.cal').onclick = function(e) {
  Calendly.initPopupWidget({
    url: 'https://calendly.com/xxxxx'
  });
};
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  font: 1ch/1.25 'Segoe UI';
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#TOS {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

label {
  display: inline-table;
  margin: 0 4px;
}

.chx::before {
  content: '\002b1b';
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.chx::after {
  content: ' I agree to Terms of Service agreement.';
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.cal {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: white;
  background: lightgrey;
  outline: none;
}

#TOS:checked~.chx::before {
  content: '\002611\00fe0f';
}

#TOS:checked+.cal {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  outline: initial;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Calendy Widget</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href='https://fake.com/path/to/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
    /* This is where CSS goes */
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <input id='TOS' name="TOS" type="checkbox" value="Accept">

  <button class='cal' type='button'>Plan</button>

  <label for="TOS" class='chx'></label>

  <script src='https://fake.com/path/to/script.js'></script>
  <script>
    /* This is where JavaScript goes */
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```